# Оформление горизонтального меню

Tags: меню, html, css

Делаю горизонтальное меню:

```
<div id="f-nav">
    <ol>
        <li class="selected">Оформление заказа</li>
        <li>Доставка</li>
        <li>Получатель</li>
        <li>Подтверждение заказа</li>
        <li>Оплата</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

стили к нему

```
#f-nav {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    background: url("/images/nav-background.png") no-repeat;
    height: 79px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 968px;
}
#f-nav ol {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    counter-reset: count;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#f-nav ol li {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#f-nav ol li {
    color: #8a8378;
}
#f-nav ol li.selected {
    color: #403422;
}
#f-nav ol li:before {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    background: url("/images/nav.png") no-repeat;
    color: #fffcee;
    content: counter(count);
    counter-increment: count 1;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 47px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 46px;
}
#f-nav ol li.selected:before {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    background: url("/images/nav-selected.png") no-repeat;
    width: 45px;
}
```

В результате получается не совсем то, что хотелось бы:

[image]

Текст должен располагаться по-середине цветочка, а он смещен к верху и у меня не получается настроить нужный вывод. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: если знаете, как сделать, напишите, плиз, в скайпе, если не сложно truslivi_lev

Answer (score 3):

`line-height: *px;` попробуй. Вместо звездочки поставь ширину как у списка

Comment: +1, только не ширину, а высоту

Comment: перепутал маленько))))

Answer (score 2):

Добавь:

```
#f-nav ol li{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Вместо:

```
#f-nav ol li{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Ссылка есть на сайт?

Answer (score 2):

`vertical-align: middle;` у вас не работает потому что вы применили `position` он перебивает данное свойство.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, в конечном итоге мне плодказали сделать так. Html-код

```
<div id="f-nav">
    <ol>
        <li class="selected"><span>1</span>Оформление заказа</li>
        <li><span>2</span>Доставка</li>
        <li><span>3</span>Получатель</li>
        <li><span>4</span>Оплата</li>
        <li><span>5</span>Подтверждение заказа</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

стили к нему

```
#f-nav {
    background: url("/images/nav-background.png") no-repeat;
    height: 79px;
    width: 968px;
}
#f-nav ol {
    /* outline: 1px solid red;*/
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
#f-nav ol li {
    color: #8a8378;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 2.7;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
#f-nav ol li.selected {
    color: #403422;
}
#f-nav ol li span {
    background: url("/images/nav.png") no-repeat;
    color: #fffcee;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 47px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin-right: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 46px;
}
#f-nav ol li.selected span {
    background: url("/images/nav-selected.png") no-repeat;
    width: 45px;
}
```

Таким образом то, что надо, получилось.